# Better support for Safari 9's Pinned Sites?

Tags: feature-request

Can Stack Overflow (and the rest of the StackExchange sites) please add support for Safari 9's new pinned sites feature?

Here's what it looks like now:

[image: Safari tabs]

Focusing on the tabs on the left, notice the [S] monogram icon, next to the Facebook and GitHub icons:

[image: Focused pinned tabs]

Notice how Facebook and GitHub get nice icons, and Stack Overflow's is generated from an SVG icon. Also, when a pinned site is active, its icon becomes colored:

[image: colored facebook icon]

What's required is the addition of two meta tags in the site's header. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW20) on What's New in Safari:

> #### Icons for Pinned Tabs
>
> Pinned Sites allow your users to keep their favorite websites open,
>   running, and easily accessible.
>
> You can set the icon that the user sees when they pin your site by
>   providing a vector image. Use 100% black for all vectors with a
>   transparent background in SVG format and add the following markup to
>   all webpages that the icon should represent (replacing "website_icon"
>   with your own file's name).
>
> `<link rel="icon" sizes="any" mask href="website_icon.svg">`
>
> Note: This
>   markup should be placed before other  elements to
>   avoid compatibility issues with existing icons. To specify the color
>   the icon should be displayed in, add the theme-color meta element to
>   your webpage:
>
> `<meta name="theme-color" content="red">`
>
> The content attribute can
>   specify a color in hexadecimal color values (#990000) or RGB formatted
>   colors (rgb(153, 0, 0)), or recognized color-keywords, such as: red,
>   lime, or navy.

I'd love to see this feature supported.

**Edit:**

It seems that this is now sort of supported by StackOverflow.com but none of the StackExchange sites. This is confusing, because if I pin two meta sites next to each other, I'll see two letter S monograms.

Was this an un/intentional change? Can I reiterate my initial request for the rest of the network?

Comment: I saw somewhere that there's a problem with this new spec that caused all other browsers to misinterpret things and show a black icon all the time.  (I recall seeing this myself on Twitter with Firefox.)  Not saying it shouldn't be implemented eventually, just maybe hold off until it's actually ironed out.

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could remember.  It may have been a bug report on Firefox?  Linked from Hacker News?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm seeing it work with Facebook, Gmail, and GitHub. Other sites support the color but not the icon.

Comment: Looks like Safari 9's docs have been updated to support a different method: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW20

Comment: Just bumping this post.

Comment: @donut - That link seems to be dead.

Comment: @Moshe The old syntax was like `<link rel="icon" sizes="any" mask href="mask-icon.svg"> <meta name="theme-color" content="#FFDD00">`. This caused issues as other browsers tried to use it as a favicon. New syntax is `<link rel='mask-icon' href='dutch.svg' color='orange'>`. (info from [this](https://yoast.com/dev-blog/safari-pinned-tab-icon-mask-icon/))

Comment: So maybe we can get this implemented with the new syntax?